# Make div show when move mouse to the left of the screen

Tags: css

I'm making an effort to edit a website's css using userscript. It has a div and I want it to be visible only when I move mouse to the left of the screen. The div mentioned above is already on the left with the width of 220px and the height is through out all the page. I want to make it to show only when I move my mouse to around 110px from the left. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How far too the left? Anywhere on the left, or just within certain y-value ranges? What have you tried? :)

Comment: This is a very vague question.  Also.. what happens for users who don't use a mouse?

Comment: add some sample code that you have tried so far

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry for my vague question above. The div mentioned above is already on the left with the width of 220px and the height is through out all the page.  I want to make it to show only when I move my mouse to around 110px from the left. Again, I'm very sorry for my careless question above. I'm new to this css thing so what I managed so far is make the div hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more specific about the "left of the screen." If there is a div to the left that we can target you could use

```
$("#left").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#right").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $("#right").hide();
});
```

here is an example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wob6bj2/)